# php display mysql table from user input? in the part of Json Restful web services?

Tags: php, mysql, json, restful-url

I am new to PHP.

I followed [this](http://www.techrecite.com/how-to-create-json-using-data-from-mysql-database/) to Display JSON data from Mysql Tables

Here I am getting one table as output at a time..

So,in this I want to display tables from user input.

like

```
www.google.com/myjson.php?/tablename
www.google.com/myjson.php?=tablename
```

Here is the code

```
<?php
//Create Database connection
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$db) {
    die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select the Database
mysql_select_db("test_json",$db);

//Replace * in the query with the column names.
$result = mysql_query("select * from employee", $db);  

//Create an array
$json_response = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['id_employee'] = $row['id_employee'];
    $row_array['emp_name'] = $row['emp_name'];
    $row_array['designation'] = $row['designation'];
    $row_array['date_joined'] = $row['date_joined'];
    $row_array['salary'] = $row['salary'];
    $row_array['id_dept'] = $row['id_dept'];

    //push the values in the array
    array_push($json_response,$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($json_response);

//Close the database connection
fclose($db);
```

?>

Here its for the part of Table name of employee
so this should be like

```
 www.google.com/myjson.php?/employee
```

please suggest me of this kind,because I have n number of tables to Display and I want to use them in the Android/iphone.

Comment: Bad practice the way you want to do it. Also you'd need to access `$_GET` and actually set a `key=value` pair to be able to find the requested table name

Comment: you mean you want json for other tables too

Comment: its not fclose($db); mysql_close($db);

Comment: @Kapil gopinath Please be careful when reviewing edits that change the meaning of the program, or otherwise introduce radical changes to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//Create Database connection
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$db) {
    die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select the Database
mysql_select_db("test_json",$db);

$tableNm  = isset($_GET['tablename']) ? trim($_GET['tablename']) : '';
if($tableNm){
    //Replace * in the query with the column names.
    $result = mysql_query("select * from $tableNm", $db);  

    //Create an array
    $json_response = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        foreach($row as $key=>$val){
            $row_array[$key] = $val;     
        }
        //push the values in the array
        array_push($json_response,$row_array);
    }
    echo json_encode($json_response);
}
//Close the database connection
mysql_close($db);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assumes you have input url's in the below formats.

```
$url ="www.google.com/myjson.php?/tablename";
//or
$url ="www.google.com/myjson.php?=tablename";
```

You can parse it using [parse_url](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to retrieve the table name.

Then assign tablename into query and make it run.

```
$url = parse_url($url);

if ($url['query'] <> '') {

    $table = str_replace(array("/","="),'',$url['query']);

}


//Create Database connection
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$db) {
    die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select the Database
mysql_select_db("test_json",$db);

//Replace * in the query with the column names.
$result = mysql_query("select * from $table", $db);  

//Create an array
$json_response = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    foreach($row as $key=>$val){
            $row_array[$key] = $val;     
    }
        //push the values in the array
        array_push($json_response,$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($json_response);

//Close the database connection
mysql_close($db);
```

P.S. Usage of mysql_* functions is not recommended.

Instead you can use [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** or [pdo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** functions.